# Checking whether an item is a list

Tags: scheme

As `list?` is not a primitive in Scheme as per SICP, I am looking for its equivalent primitive. I considered these alternatives:-

- `pair?` but it returns `#f` for `'()` .
- `pair?` or `null?`. Looks ok but is it?

Is there anything simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no primitive since a list is either `()` or a `pair?` whose `cdr` is a list. Since a list isn't a primitive but a compound of pairs event with the empty list. `list?` can be defined as this :

```
(define (list? lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (and (pair? lst)
           (list? (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: The standard RNRS `list?` returns `#f` for circular lists, so that's not a suitable drop-in replacement, btw.

Comment: @Shawn True, but the [cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) makes it slightly more complex and takes away focus from the definition of a `list?` towards what it is not. Btw. `list?` came in R4RS so it's kind of new :)